# Dos reportes en IReport

Tags: pdf, jasper-reports, ireport

Estoy creando un reporte en `IReport 4.0.1` de la siguiente forma donde genero una guia de despacho a un usuario, este reporte debe generar dos copias una para el que recibe el despacho y el encargado.

Primero genere una vista con el reporte en general
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 <pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
```

Despues cree otra vista y con un subreporte lo copie 2 veces.

```
 <pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy buscando la forma que el reporte sea repulsivo al momento de imprimir, es decir la hoja se divida en 2 una parte arriba y la otra abajo de la mitad.

Algo asi por ejemplo

```
 -----------------------
| -------------------  | 
| |ORIGINAL         |  |   
| |1 Linea          |  |   
| |2 Linea          |  | 
| |3 Linea          |  | 
| -------------------  |  
|----------------------| <---MITAD
| -------------------  | 
| |COPIA            |  |   
| |1 Linea          |  | 
| |2 Linea          |  | 
| |3 Linea          |  |    
| -------------------  |
------------------------
```

Pero en mi reporte actual, ejemplo si despacho poco items la hoja se me descuadra quedando algo asi(Max 10 items por despachar).

---

```
| -------------------  | 
| |ORIGINAL         |  |   
| |1 Linea          |  |   
| |2 Linea          |  | 
| -------------------  |  
|----------------------| 
| -------------------  | 
| |COPIA            |  | <-- MITAD   
| |1 Linea          |  | 
| |2 Linea          |  |   
| -------------------  |
|                      | 
|                      | 
|                      | 
------------------------
```

Comment: No creo que sea la mejor solución, pero ¿si colocas un subreporte en la banda Title y el otro en la banda Page Header y les das el mismo HEIGHT te funciona?

Comment: hola, gracias por tu respuesta. dices el mismo Height a los subreportes?

Comment: No, según entiendo has creado dos sub reportes y los has metido en uno. En el reporte que contiene los dos subreportes, mi idea es que dejes con el mismo height las dos bandas que te comentaba.

Comment: @Garrizano Les agrege el mismo alto a las 2 bandas y igual